# Why do my logs only log once in a flask app when called multiple times?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I've just recently setup a logging module and am kind of confused since the log statements only happen once throughout a program's lifetime even though I am going through the functions multiple times.

I decided to try to play around with Flask's internal logs but ends up having the same effects. I'm guessing that I'm missing some sort of configuration.

**log.conf**:

```
[handlers]
keys=stream_handler, file_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file_handler

[handler_stream_handler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file_handler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=('python.log','a')

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

**Some code snippets**:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def some_func():
    """stubbed function for testing"""
    app.logger.info('testing flask logs')
    logger.debug("Hoping this logs multiple times")

app.route('/')
def endpoint():
    some_func()
    return ""
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would expect to see a route in your code.

Comment: @KlausD.

I've added a route to add more visualization.
So, I almost expect to see those two log statements appear each time i hit the / endpoint. I'll end up only seeing it on the first GET request, though.